# Parent Layout visiblity Invisible/visible on Button Click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, visibility

I am trying to change visibility of `Relative Layout` in my code on `Button` click, But i am facing a weird behavior.

Whenever i click on my Button say A first time, it shows the Relative layout say RA, and after clicking it(Second time) again it hides RA. The problem i am facing here is when i click on A second time it also hides its parent layout, And then on clicking it again it shows RA and its parent layout, After that it hides and shows both layouts on click event.

How this is happening here,

Here is my Code
this is my XML

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainscreenrelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        android:background="@drawable/setting_icon_hover"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_mainpage_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mainscreenrelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
  >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_settings_monthlyissue"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/monthly_issue_select"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_settings_changepassword"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_settings_monthlyissue"
       android:background="@drawable/password_select" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_settings_logout"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_settings_changepassword"
       android:background="@drawable/logout_select" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my CODE in Activity Class:

```
  Button _settings;
  RelativeLayout __settingslayout;
  boolean isSettingsClicked = false;
     ........ 
     ........

 _settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonSettings);
_settingslayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL_mainpage_settings);
_settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isSettingsClicked == false) {
            _settings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setting_icon);

            _settingslayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isSettingsClicked = true;
        } else if (isSettingsClicked == true) {
            _settingslayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            _settings
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setting_icon_hover);
            isSettingsClicked = false;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is , RelativeLayout with id android:id="@+id/mainscreenrelativeLayout2" is also hiding on click event, as you can see i haven't used this id in my Activity.

Comment: yes ,  they belong to same parent

Comment: your button's parent layout is not hiding on button click?? only layout RA is disappearing on button click??

Comment: Yes.This shows a view with Settings button on right side and having background White.And shows a view having 3 buttons just above it.When click on settings button it either show/hide thee layout having 3 buttons only.Settings button and white background stayed the same.

Comment: try to set icon to your setting button, on click event,
Change the setting button resource as i did, then tell me , is it same?
because i realized  that when i didnt change my setting button background it works fine, but when i change it, it changes its parent layout also

Comment: I tried it and works well.I think this is your image's issue.Check the size of image using for settings button.

Comment: yes it was my image problem i guess, I just changed my images, now its working fine..